# Photoelectric effect in a a frequency range

Tags: photoelectric-effect

I know how to calculate the kinetic energy of the emitted electrons

### $$KE=hf-\phi$$

And the number of the emitted electrons, but this is valid for a certain frequency

### $$N=\frac{IA}{hf}=\frac{P}{hf}$$

What happens if I have a frequency range? for example between λ1 and λ2?

BTW: It's not homework, I'm an engineering student,  not a physics student

Comment: then you get an electron beam with electrons of different velocity (that is in the corresponding range)...

Comment: but in the photoelectric effect experiments when the light filters change, the generated current changes (keeping the light source constant)
I understand that if what you propose happens then the generated currents is the sum of all the electrons emitted by all the frequencies, but it does not correspond to the experiments

Comment: I thought that possibilities can be 1) I got that wrong (most likely) 2) light filter is not ideal 3) light source is not ideal 4) not enough energy to strike off electrons when having longer wavelength 5) insufficient voltage when having longer wavelength (meter, wire, etc aren't ideal)

Comment: Wouldn't it be $$\frac{1}{h}\int_{f_1}^{f_2}\frac{dP}{df} df = \frac{1}{h}\int_{f_1}^{f_2}I(f) df$$ where $I$ in this case is the power per unity frequency? The spectra of light sources and absorption of filters will both vary with frequency. If the filters are narrow and the experiment doesn't need to be extremely precise, then you can make an approximation that there is one frequency $f$, otherwise one needs to do the integral.

Comment: How big an energy range are you thinking about? To me the *photoelectric effect* refers to a very limited energy range. Basically enough energy to knock out an electron from the surface of a metal substance from the metallic conduction band, and without the photon to have enough energy to ionize electrons bound the the metal atom's orbitals. You can also us more energetic electrons for techniques like ESCA where you're getting information on the bonding energies of loosely bound electrons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the [cross-section of radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoelectric_effect#Cross_section) reacting with the electrons in the sample. The cross-section depends on the energy of the photon and the atomic number of the target.

The photoelectric cross-section for a particular geometry and energy is roughly given by:

$$\sigma_E = n_1\dfrac{Z^{n_2}}{E^3} $$

where 
$n_1$ and $n_2$ are fitted constants
Z the atomic number of the target
E the energy of the photon

So to the the total intensity you'd have to integrate the product of the flux of the photons for a particular energy E times the cross-section for that energy.

All of this would be predicated on the restriction that the photon is of low energy and would be adsorbed near the surface. If the electrons have to escape from within the sample rather than from the surface of the sample, the the electron's cross-section would have to be considered.

As seen in the diagram below (from [Lecture Note on Photon interactions and Cross Sections, H.Hirayama](http://rcwww.kek.jp/research/shield/photon_r.pdf#page=4)) even a limited diagram the cross-section for photons in matter is complicated. The diagram is for high energy photons which leaves out all the detail of the elements absorption edges due to the binding energy of the electrons which occur at lower energies than shown.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If there is a frequency range of source of light used then you will get a whole electron beam with different speeds accordingly.