# Number of emitted electrons by photoelectric effect

Tags: photoelectric-effect

I search in some post, and say that the number $N$ of emitted electrons is

$$N=\frac{IA}{hf}=\frac{P}{hf}$$

but $f$ is for fixed incident frequency

what happens if I want to calculate $N$ for a range of frequency for example between $f1$ and $f2$ ?
I think that the general formula for $N$ is

$$N=\frac{IA}{h}\int_{f1}^{f2}\frac{df}{f}$$

Is it correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Photoelectric effect in a a frequency range](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/548465/photoelectric-effect-in-a-a-frequency-range)

Comment: I think in the answer the equation are incorrect

Comment: I think in the answer the equation are incorrect

Comment: What answer to which equation?

Comment: the answer of uhoh, the integral that it proposes is Pdf / df = P then the integration variables of cancel which is not possible, also P / df is not equal to I (f), also I (f) I can calculate and as the result is a constant I can take it out of the integral

Comment: @RicardoCasimiro, if you weren't satisfied with the answer you got, why did you give a check mark?

Comment: it was my mistake...

Comment: No definitions of the symbols used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First issue, your equation doesn't give a number of carriers generated, but rather the number generated per unit time; that is, a rate of carrier generation.

With that in mind, it's conceivable your equation could apply to some real situation.

But more often, the intensity is not uniform across all frequencies, so your constant *I* term should be $I(f)$.

Also, most photoelectric materials don't produce an electric carrier for every single incident photon, or the electric carriers might go elsewhere rather than be usefully measured. So there is an efficiency factor, often designated $\eta$, which may also be a function of frequency, $\eta(f)$.

Then, the formula for the rate of carrier generation becomes

$$ N = \frac{A}{h}\int_{f_1}^{f_2}\frac{I(f)\eta(f)}{f}df$$